# Galilean Symmetry of Newtonian Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, symmetry, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

So for the equations of motion to be symmetric about a transformation from $(t,x)$ to $(\tau, y)$, the following must be true (for Newtonian mechanics):
$$m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = f \left( x, \frac{dx}{dt}, t \right)$$
$$m \frac{d^2 y}{d\tau^2} = f \left( y, \frac{dy}{d\tau}, \tau \right).$$
Given the Galilean transformation $y=x-vt$, we can see that $m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = m \frac{d^2 y}{d\tau^2}$, so for the equations of motion to be invariant, it must be the case that:
$$f \left( x, \frac{dx}{dt}, t \right)=f \left( x-vt, \frac{dx}{dt}-v, t \right)$$
I thought that in general, Newtonian mechanics was invariant to a Galilean transformation, but given even a trivial force like a spring $f(x)=-kx$, it is not the case that $f(x)=f(x-vt)$. Is this analysis correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all systems in Newtonian mechanics are invariant under Galilean transformations. For the spring problem: there is a hidden parameter: the *equilibrium position* of the spring. When we boost to the new reference frame, we need to consider the distance of the particle from the equilibrium.

$$ F(y) = -k(y - vt - x_0) = -k(y - y_0 (t))$$

We see that the force on the particle no longer depends solely on the location of the particle in the $y$-frame, but also the time being considered. In this frame, the force law is time dependent!

Examples of forces with Galilean invariance include those whose interactions depend only on the distance between particles, such as Newton's law of gravitation. The major point with Galilean tranformations is that they describe how to move from one inertial reference frame to another, and these are the frames in which general descriptions of physical laws should apply.